# How to send data from React front-end to Nodejs Express back-end on button click

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, post

Disclaimer: I am new to React and Nodejs and have of course looked at all the current similar posts but none of them were able to help me fully so please don't mark as duplicate.

In my Nodejs `index.js` I have:

```
app.get('/list-certs', function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile("certs.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       console.log( data );
       res.send( data );
   });
})

app.post('/list-certs', function (req, res) {
    res.send('POST request: ' + req.body.domain-input);
    console.log('post is working!')
});
```

And in my React `App.js` I have:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.callApi()
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        json: res.map(x => x),
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}


callApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/list-certs');
  const body = await response.json();

  if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
  return body;
};


handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({domainInputValue: event.target.value});
}


click() {
}


render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/list-certs" className="add-cert-form" method="post">
        <h1>Add new domain</h1>
        <h5 className="domain-label">Name:</h5>
        <Input className="domain-input" value={this.state.domainInputValue} onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}}></Input>
        <Button onClick={this.click} className="domain-button" type='primary'>Add</Button>
      </form>
      .
      .
      .
}
```

How do I send the data in my input field `domain-input` to my back-end when the button `domain-button` is clicked? I know something needs to go in the `click()` but I'm not sure what.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Your click function will look like it:

```
async click() {
    const { domainInputValue } = this.state;
    const request = await fetch('/echo/json', {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: { domainInputValue }
    });

}
```

Comment: Good answer, just to avoid confusion your `request` var is actually the request `response` value;

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting a "Cannot POST /list-certs" when I click the button. Am I missing something else? Do I need different paths for my GET and POST calls?

Comment: @tnoel999888: I think you need to stringify the data using JSON.stringify({domainInputValue})

Comment: @UmairAhmed does this go in the 'body:' declaration of the click() method?

Comment: @Dyo so should I change it to `const response` instead of `const request`?

Comment: Also don't I need to do something with this request variable? As right now it's just being declared

Comment: @tnoel999888 Yes but it's just about naming conventions, you could name it like you want, you can extract the response the same way you did in `callApi` but your server is sending a text so you'll need to do `const body = await response.text()` instead of `json()`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that fetch already convert object to json.

Comment: @Dyo thank you to tell me about the const name, you are right, it got weird.

Comment: Is `fetch` the correct function to use for this POST request? I use `fetch` in my GET request and it doesn't seem right to be using the same for both

Comment: @tnoel999888 The Fetch API provides an interface for fetching resources (including across the network). It will seem familiar to anyone who has used XMLHttpRequest.